# How to extract an array of fields from an array of JSON documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have 2 mongodb collections, `stu_creds` and `stu_profile`. I first want to retrieve all the student records from `stu_creds` where `stu_pref_contact` is the email and then for those `stu_id`s I want to retrieve the complete profile from `stu_profile`. The problem is, the first query returns an array of JSON documents, with each document holding one field, the `stu_id`. Here is my query and the result:

```
db.stu_creds.find({"stu_pref_contact" : "email"}, {'_id' : 1})
```

Result:

```
[{ "_id" : ObjectId("51927cc93080baac04000001") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51927d7b3080baac04000002") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519bb011c5c5035b2a000002") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519ce3d09f047a192b000010") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519e6dc0f919cfdc66000003") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b39be0c74f0e3d23000012") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b39ca9c74f0e3d23000014") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b39cb7c74f0e3d23000016") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b39e87c74f0e3d23000018") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b39f2fc74f0e3d2300001a") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51b39f47c74f0e3d2300001c") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518d454deb1e3a525e000009") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bc8381dd10286e5b000002") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bc83f7dd10286e5b000004") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bc85cbdd10286e5b000006") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bc8630dd10286e5b000008") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bc8991dd10286e5b00000a") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bc8a43dd10286e5b00000c") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bc8a7ddd10286e5b00000e") },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bc8acadd10286e5b000010") }]
```

The thing is, I don't think I can use the above array as part of an `$in` clause for my second query to retrieve the student profiles. I have to walk through the array and and create a new array which is just an array of object ids rather than an array of JSON docs.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Array.map (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This allows you to perform a transform on each element of the array, returning you a new array of the transformed items.

```
var arrayOfIds = result.map(function(item){ return item._id; });
```

Array.map was introduced in ECMAScript 5. If you're using node.js, a modern browser, or an Array polyfill, it should be available to use.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, am I missing something or is all you want the following:

```
var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
    results.push(yourArray[i]._id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$or`:

```
db.stu_profile.find({ $or : results }) // `results` is your list of ObjectId's
```

But it's considerably slower than `$in`, so I would suggest using one of the other answers ;)